# Public Holiday Checker (UK)

Tags: java

I need to prevent entry to a car park system during public holidays, but instead of making more classes i was hoping it could be done within my existing method. my question is, is there such thing in java that already has public holiday dates predefined and can be used within if state or some sort to prevent entry if todays date matches those list of public holiday dates.

this is my existing method.which as you can see checks if its weekend, saturday and sunday, both which are public day off. but in uk there are more days such as bank holidays, but how do i define all the rest of the dates.

```
public boolean checkHoliday(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
    if (dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 7){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    /*add method for further holiday date check*/ 

}
```

Comment: if this is achievable, i can define the holiday dates in a file for the current year. but how do i compare todays date to the format of file date dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Where is the car park situated? The actual holidays will vary between countries so you can't for example use a list of English bank holidays to determine Scottish public holidays.

Answer (score 3):

You can grab an XML from [google public holiday for UK](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.uk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic).

If you prefer ICAL format, [here it is](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/en.uk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics).

And if you like to check what's in it just [look here](https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?src=en.uk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com).

Comment: Your links are broken for me, but if you are referring to the Google 'UK Holidays' calendar that has a lot of days like "Mother's Day" which aren't holidays at all.

Comment: links are broken yeah

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite a library that you can just call locally but http://www.holidaywebservice.com/ is a web service that will give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library is written in C#, but a JSON/XML Webservice is available.

https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.Date

**JSON Webservice**

Get the public holidays for United Kingdom for the year 2018
http://date.nager.at/api/v1/get/GB/2018
More information about the available API methods you can found [here](https://date.nager.at/swagger/index.html)

**Java Example**

```
//https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyValue value = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://date.nager.at/api/v1/get/US/2018"), PublicHoliday[].class);
```

**PublicHoliday.class**

```
public class PublicHoliday
{
    public String Date;
    public String LocalName;
    public String Name;
    public String CountryCode;
    public Boolean Fixed;
    public Boolean CountyOfficialHoliday;
    public Boolean CountyAdministrationHoliday;
    public Boolean Global;
    public String[] Counties;
    public int LaunchYear;
}
```

**Example JSON data retrieved**

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2017-01-01",
    "localName": "New Year's Day",
    "name": "New Year's Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-16",
    "localName": "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day",
    "name": "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-20",
    "localName": "Inauguration Day",
    "name": "Inauguration Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": false,
    "counties": [
      "US-DC",
      "US-LA",
      "US-MD",
      "US-VA"
    ],
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-20",
    "localName": "Washington's Birthday",
    "name": "Presidents' Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-05-29",
    "localName": "Memorial Day",
    "name": "Memorial Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-07-04",
    "localName": "Independence Day",
    "name": "Independence Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-09-04",
    "localName": "Labor Day",
    "name": "Labor Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-09-09",
    "localName": "Columbus Day",
    "name": "Columbus Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": false,
    "counties": [
      "US-AL",
      "US-AZ",
      "US-CO",
      "US-CT",
      "US-DC",
      "US-GA",
      "US-ID",
      "US-IL",
      "US-IN",
      "US-IA",
      "US-KS",
      "US-KY",
      "US-LA",
      "US-ME",
      "US-MD",
      "US-MA",
      "US-MS",
      "US-MO",
      "US-MT",
      "US-NE",
      "US-NH",
      "US-NJ",
      "US-NM",
      "US-NY",
      "US-NC",
      "US-OH",
      "US-OK",
      "US-PA",
      "US-RI",
      "US-SC",
      "US-TN",
      "US-UT",
      "US-VA",
      "US-WV"
    ],
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-11-10",
    "localName": "Veterans Day",
    "name": "Veterans Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": false,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-23",
    "localName": "Thanksgiving Day",
    "name": "Thanksgiving Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": 1863
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-25",
    "localName": "Christmas Day",
    "name": "Christmas Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  }
]
```